# ¿Cómo hacer que PHP al ingresar al INDEX no regrese al LOGIN al retroceder la PAGINA?

Tags: php, login, index

Básicamente en mi proyecto tengo "index.php" el cual valida si no hay una sesión activa y redirecciona a "session.php". Dentro del "session.php" el cual valida los datos de inicio de sesión de un formulario y redirecciona de nuevo a "index.php" en donde tengo el contenido principal. El asunto es cuando estoy en "index.php" al retroceder una pagina del navegador me regresa a "session.php" y me gustaría que se quedara en "index.php" hasta que termine la sesión.

A continuación el código del index.php:

```
<?php

include 'conect.php';

session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

if (!isset($user_id)) {
    header('location: session.php');
}

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($user_id);
    session_destroy();
    header('location: session.php');
}

?>
```

Enseguida del código de session.php:

```
<?php

include 'conect.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['iniciarSesion'])) {

    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
    $contraseña = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, md5($_POST['contraseña']));

    $select = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `usuario` WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND contraseña = '$contraseña'") or die('query failed');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
    if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['contraseña'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['usuario']) && empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {
            $message[] = 'Usuario y ontraseña faltante.';
        } else if (empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {
            $message[] = 'Contraseña faltante.';
        } else if (empty($_POST['usuario'])) {
            $message[] = 'Usuario faltante.';
        } else if(isset($row['usuario'])) {
            if (isset($row['contraseña'])) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id_usuario'];
                    header('location: index.php');
                } 
            }
        } else if(!isset($row['usuario']) || !isset($row['contraseña'])){
            $message[] = 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta.';
        }  
    }
}

?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme:3

Comment: Creo que simplemente debes agregar un `else` aquí `if (!isset($user_id)) {header('location: session.php');} else {header('location: index.php');}`

Comment: @DjCrazy Lo intente y me provoca el siguiente error: Esta página no funciona **La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.**
Borrar las cookies.
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**